# Rails 6 How to have multiple fields of a model as references to another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model, reference

I'm currently creating a Rails app using rails 6. I have model named user_teams and a model named players. What I want to do is have multiple fields in the user_teams model such as player_one, player_two...player_six that are each an individual reference to a player.

I have implemented this but in a slightly janky way. I have the six fields in my user_team model and each is an integer of the id associated with the chosen player. I feel like there is a much better way to do this but I can't figure out how. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also once I have the references set up properly, how can I validate each player reference so that duplicate players can't be in the same user_team?

Example
UserTeam
  player_one: 1
  player_two: 1

Would not be allowed but

UserTeam
  player_one: 1
  player_two: 2

Would be allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard [many to many association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) and what you want is a join table that joins players and teams:

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :positions
  has_many :user_teams, through: :positions
end

class UserTeam < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :positions
  has_many :players, through: :positions
end

# generate the model and migration with:
# rails g model position player:belongs_to user_team:belongs_to
class Position < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :user_team
end
```

Another way to set this up would be with [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) but as there is no join model there is no way to access any additional columns on the join table and you cannot join it directly.

You can validate the uniqueness of a player on a team by using validates_uniqueness with the `scope` option:

```
class Position < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :user_team
  validates :player_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_team_id }
end
```

This will prevent most duplicates but is [prone to race conditions which could lead to duplicate data being inserted](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations) so it should be complimented with a unique index that enforces the constraint on the database level:

```
class CreatePositions < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :positions do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user_team, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :player, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :positions, [:user_team_id, :player_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: This was perfect and so simple. Can't believe I didn't realise it haha. Thanks for that @max!

Answer (score 0):

UserTeam model should have field `name` &
Player model should have field `user_team_id`

## model/UserTeam.rb

```
class UserTeam < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players
end
```

## model/Player.rb

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user_team
end
```